# Hyperref warnings casued by line-breaks in author field in a Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I'm compiling the following in OverLeaf (pdflatex / TexLive 2019) and getting:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): removing `\\' on input line 7.
```

I found many advices online to use line break to force moving second author to a new line. However, it somehow interferes with hyperref and all that PDF string business. Any advice on how to bypass this? Or maybe it is OverLeaf's problem?

Thank you!

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[final,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\title{Title}
\author{Author1 \\ Author2}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{Test block}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item item1
            \item item2
        \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly overleaf-related.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning is actually more an information: It means that hyperref ignored the `\\` when building the author entry for the pdf properties. You then get simply the two authors:

[image]

You can get rid of the warning (and if you want replace the `\\` with something else) with `\texorpdfstring`:

```
 \author{Author1 \texorpdfstring{\\}{and} Author2}
```

which would give:

[image]

(The additional quotes around the author names in the first case are an odity of the adobe reader, sometimes it decides that quotes should be there ...)

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to disable automatic population of PDF author / title fields or specify them separately? without spilling `texorpdfstring` everywhere?

Comment: You can specify them separatly with `\hypersetup{pdfauthor=...}` *after* the `\author` command. But you can't get rid of the warning with it, as the beamer definition of `\author` contains such a call too, so you would have to redefine `\author` too.

Comment: Is it possible to redefine `\hypersetup` command instead? To make it nop? So that on the call within `\author` command it would do nothing

Comment: Well naturally you can redefine if (if you no longer need it). But why do you try so hard to avoid a \texorpdfstring (or accept a warning in the log)? Redefining hypersetup will only help with author and title, if you have unusual commands in \section or other place relevant for bookmarks you will get such warnings too.